# Saving tidypmc output which forms a list object and saving it into individual file based on PMCIDs

Tags: r, database, pubmed, tidypmc

So im making a query it returns me PMCIDs which is again used to query using tidypmc libray to parse table which contains metadata from various papers, which is finally returned as list.Some of the PMCIDs will be empty since it doesn't have a proper table tag etc. So now I want to save each PMCIDs into individual file, which i tried but i got an error, its not that straightforward if i get it. Since under each list of PMCIDs there are multiple table which should be also need to saved under that PMCIDs.

Not sure how to proceed but a way i can think is each PMCID result should be written inside individual folder if a PMCID contain 4 table then 4 table under that receptive PMCID folder.

Below is the code I m using

```
library("europepmc")
library(xml2)
library(tidypmc)
b <-epmc_search(query = 'acute myeloid leukemia drug studies',output = 'parsed',limit = 20)
a <- b %>% select(pmid,pmcid)
a <- a[complete.cases(a),]
c <- a$pmcid

pub_tables <- lapply(c, function(pmc_id) {
  message("-- Trying ", pmc_id, "...")
  doc <- tryCatch(pmc_xml(pmc_id), 
                  error = function(e) {
                    message("------ Failed to recover PMCID")
                    return(NULL)
                  })
  if(!is.null(doc)) { 
    #-- If succeed, try to get table
    tables <- pmc_table(doc)
    if(!is.null(tables)) {
      #-- If succeed, try to get table name
      table_caps <- pmc_caption(doc) %>%
        filter(tag == "table")
      #names(tables) <- paste(table_caps$label, table_caps$text, sep = " - ")
    }
    return(tables) 
  } else {
    #-- If fail, return NA
    return(NA)
  }
  Sys.sleep(sample(1:10))  
})
names(pub_tables) <- c


for (i in 1:length(pub_tables)) {
  
  write.csv(pub_tables[i], file=paste0("output/", names(pub_tables)[i], ".txt"))
  }
```

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
> check.names = TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows:
> 28, 8, 20

I will `dput` my sample query i tried with 20 so that the object is small

```
dput(pub_tables)
list(PMC6968541 = NULL, PMC7170320 = NULL, PMC7269076 = NULL, 
    PMC7219522 = NULL, PMC7372828 = list(`Table 1` = structure(list(
        X1 = c("AML with recurrent genetic abnormalities", "AML with t(8;21)(q22;q22.1);RUNX1-RUNX1T1", 
        "AML with inv. (16)(p13.1q22) or t(16;16)(p13.1;q22);CBFB-MYH11", 
        "APL with PML-RARA", "AML with t(9;11)(p21.3;q23.3);MLLT3-KMT2A", 
        "AML with t(6;9)(p23;q34.1);DEK-NUP214", "AML with inv. (3)(q21.3q26.2) or t(3;3)(q21.3;q26.2); GATA2, MECOM", 
        "AML (megakaryoblastic) with t(1;22)(p13.3;q13.3);RBM15-MKL1", 
        "Provisional entity: AML with BCR-ABL1", "AML with mutated NPM1", 
        "AML with biallelic mutations of CEBPA", "Provisional entity: AML with mutated RUNX1", 
        "AML with myelodysplasia-related changes", "Therapy-related myeloid neoplasms", 
        "AML, NOS", "AML with minimal differentiation", "AML without maturation", 
        "AML with maturation", "Acute myelomonocytic leukemia", 
        "Acute monoblastic/monocytic leukemia", "Pure erythroid leukemia", 
        "Acute megakaryoblastic leukemia", "Acute basophilic leukemia", 
        "Acute panmyelosis with myelofibrosis", "Myeloid sarcoma", 
        "Myeloid proliferations related to Down syndrome", "Transient abnormal myelopoiesis (TAM)", 
        "Myeloid leukemia associated with Down syndrome"), X2 = c(NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -28L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), caption = "The 2016 WHO classification of acute myeloid leukemia (AML) and related neoplasms", footnotes = "APL, acute promyelocytic leukemia; NOS, not otherwise specified"), 
        `Table 2` = structure(list(`Functional category` = c("Myeloid transcription-factor genes", 
        "Nucleophosmin (NPM1) gene", "Tumor suppressor genes", 
        "Signaling genes", "DNA methylation", "Chromatin modifier", 
        "Cohesin complex", "Splicing factors"), `Gene members` = c("Transcription factor fusions by chromosomal rearrangements, such as t(8;21)(q22;q22); RUNX1-RUNX1T1 and inv(16)(p13.1q22) or t(16;16)(p13.1;q22); CBFB-MYH11GATA2, RUNX1 and CEBPA", 
        "NPM1", "TP53, WT1, PHF6", "FLT3, KIT, PTPN11, RAS", 
        "DNMT3A, TET2, IDH1, IDH2", "ASXL1, EZH2 and KMT2A", 
        "STAG1, STAG2, RAD21, SMC1A, SMC3,", "SRSF2, SF3B1, U2AF1, ZRSR2"
        ), `Role in AML Leukemogenesis` = c("Transcriptional deregulation and impaired hematopoietic differentiation.", 
        "Aberrant cytoplasmic localization of NPM1 and its interacting proteins", 
        "Transcriptional deregulation and impaired degradation via the negative regulator (MDM2 and PTEN oncogenes)", 
        "Proliferative advantage through the RAS-RAF, JAK-STAT, and PI3K-AKT signaling pathways", 
        "Deregulation of DNA methylation and oncometabolite production", 
        "Deregulation of chromatin modification and impairment of methyltransferases function", 
        "Impairment of accurate chromosome segregation and transcriptional regulation", 
        "Deregulated RNA processing and aberrant splicing patterns"
        )), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
        "data.frame"), caption = "Functional categories of genes that are commonly mutated in acute myeloid leukemia (AML)"), 
        `Table 3` = structure(list(`Risk profiles` = c("Favorable", 
        "Favorable", "Favorable", "Favorable", "Favorable", "Intermediate", 
        "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", 
        "Adverse", "Adverse", "Adverse", "Adverse", "Adverse", 
        "Adverse", "Adverse", "Adverse", "Adverse", "Adverse"
        ), Subgroups = c("t(8;21)(q22;q22.1); RUNX1-RUNX1T1", 
        "inv (16)(p13.1q22) or t(16;16)(p13.1;q22); CBFB-MYH11", 
        "Mutated NPM1 without FLT3-ITD", "Mutated NPM1 with FLT3-ITDlow", 
        "Biallelic mutated CEBPA", "Mutated NPM1 and FLT3-ITDhigh", 
        "Wild-type NPM1 without FLT3-ITD", "Wild-type NPM1 with FLT3-ITDlow", 
        "t(9;11)(p21.3;q23.3); MLLT3-KMT2A", "Cytogenetic abnormalities not classified", 
        "t(6;9)(p23;q34.1); DEK-NUP214", "t(v;11q23.3); KMT2A rearranged", 
        "t(9;22)(q34.1;q11.2); BCR-ABL1", "inv (3)(q21.3q26.2) or t(3;3)(q21.3;q26.2); GATA2,MECOM(EVI1)", 
        "Complex karyotype, monosomal karyotype", "-5 or del(5q); −7; −17/abn(17p)", 
        "Wild-type NPM1 and FLT3-ITDhigh", "Mutated RUNX1", "Mutated ASXL1", 
        "Mutated TP53")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
        "tbl", "data.frame"), caption = "Risk stratification of AML according To 2017 ELN recommendations [24]", footnotes = "Low, low allelic ratio (< 0.5); high, high allelic ratio (≥0.5)")), 
    PMC7374966 = list(`Table 1` = structure(list(`Year of publication, region/country (reference)` = c("1970, West Virginia (USA)[7, 10]", 
    "1983, Thailand[5]", "1990, Texas (USA)[8]", "1992, Mississippi (USA)[12]", 
    "1994, Maryland (USA)[13]", "2009, India[11]", "2010, Germany[14]", 
    "2011, Japan[9]", "2018, Wisconsin (USA)[6]", "2019, Switzerland(present case)"
    ), `Underlying conditions` = c("1 year-old male, no underlying conditions", 
    "20 year-old female, no underlying conditions", "29 year-old male, cocaine abuse", 
    "64 year-old male, kidney transplantation", "32 year-old female, lymphocytic lymphoma with leukemic transformation (neutropenia)", 
    "10 year-old female, T-cell acute lymphoblastic leukemia", 
    "78 year-old female, myelodysplastic syndrome", "61 year-old male, mantle cell lymphoma, allogeneic HSCT", 
    "15 year-old male, B-cell lymphoblastic leukemia (neutropenia)", 
    "71 year-old, acute myeloid leukemia (neutropenia)"), `Organs affected` = c("Mediastinum, lungs, pericardium", 
    "Soft tissues (breast), lungs, mediastinum, liver, gastro-intestinal tract", 
    "Endocardium, blood, skin, heart, lungs, kidneys, brain, muscles", 
    "Lungs, myocardium, brain, kidney, thyroid", "Lungs, pericardium", 
    "Sinus, soft tissues (facial)", "Sinus, soft tissues (facial), brain", 
    "Lungs, heart, spleen, kidney, bladder, thyroid", "Sinus, lungs", 
    "Lungs"), Species = c("C. incongruus", "C. incongruus", "Conidiobolus spp.", 
    "C. coronatus", "C. incongruus", "C. coronatus", "C. incongruus", 
    "C. lamprauges", "C. coronatus", "Conidiobolus spp."), `Treatment (dose), duration and outcome` = c("Deoxycholate amphotericin B (1 mg/kg/day), 10 weeksOutcome: cure", 
    "Co-trimoxazole (2 g/day), duration NSOutcome: death", 
    "NoneOutcome: death", "Deoxycholate amphotericin B (50 mg every other day), until deathOutcome: death", 
    "Deoxycholate amphotericin B (0.5 mg/kg/day, then 1.5 mg/kg/day) and flucytosine (150 mg/kg/day), until deathSurgeryOutcome: death", 
    "Amphotericin B (NS), until deathSurgeryOutcome: death", 
    "Liposomal amphotericin B (200 mg/day), until deathSurgeryOutcome: death", 
    "Micafungin (150 mg/day) and liposomal amphotericin B (2.5 mg/kg/day), then intravenous voriconazole (6 mg/kg/day on day 1, then 4 mg/kg/day) and micafungin (150 mg/day), until deathOutcome: death", 
    "Liposomal amphotericin B (10 mg/kg/day) and anidulafungin (1.5 mg/kg/day) and oral terbinafine (250 mg twice per day), duration NSSurgery, granulocyte transfusionOutcome: cure", 
    "Caspofungin (70 mg/day on day 1, then 50 mg/day), then liposomal amphotericin B (5 mg/kg/day), then oral isavuconazole (200 mg three times per day on day 1 and 2, then 200 mg/day), 2 monthsSurgeryOutcome: cure"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), caption = "Case reports of invasive fungal infections due to Conidiobolus spp.", footnotes = "NS Not specified")))
```

Any Suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter the search by Open Access (or the results by the isOpenAccess column)

```
library(europepmc)
b <-epmc_search(query = 'acute myeloid leukemia drug studies OPEN_ACCESS:Y',limit = 20)
pmcids <- b$pmcid[b$isOpenAccess=="Y"]
```

Then I would loop through the PMC ids and save the text and tables

```
library(tidypmc)
n <- length(pmcids)
txt <- vector("list", n)
tbl <- vector("list", n)
names(txt) <- pmcids
names(tbl) <- pmcids
for(i in 1:n){
  id <- pmcids[i]
  message("Parsing ", i, ". ", id) 
  doc <- pmc_xml(id)
  txt[[i]] <- pmc_text(doc)
  ## pmc_table returns NULL if missing, which will delete the element!
   x <- pmc_table(doc)
  if(!is.null(x)) tbl[[i]] <- x
  Sys.sleep(sample(1:3))  
}
```

Finally, collapse the tables into column names and cell values pairs.

```
library(tidyverse)
txt2 <- bind_rows(txt, .id="PMCID")
tbl2 <- bind_rows( lapply(tbl, collapse_rows), .id="PMCID")
```

The caption and footnotes are saved as attributes, so you can get those too (and a purrr expert could probably format this better)

```
attributes(tbl[[5]][[1]])
# $caption
# [1] "The 2016 WHO classification of acute myeloid leukemia (AML) and related neoplasms"
# $footnotes
# [1] "APL, acute promyelocytic leukemia; NOS, not otherwise specified"

enframe( unlist( lapply(tbl, sapply, attr, "caption"))) 
#    name               value                                                                                   
#    <chr>              <chr>                                                                                   
#  1 PMC7372828.Table 1 The 2016 WHO classification of acute myeloid leukemia (AML) and related neoplasms       
#  2 PMC7372828.Table 2 Functional categories of genes that are commonly mutated in acute myeloid leukemia (AML)
#  3 PMC7372828.Table 3 Risk stratification of AML according To 2017 ELN recommendations [24]                   
#  4 PMC7374966.Table 1 Case reports of invasive fungal infections due to Conidiobolus spp.                     
#  5 PMC7362563.Table 1 Best overall response for patients with AML at any time on treatment
```

Comment: will run and update you ..i cant up-vote right now because of my reputation thanks a ton for the update

Comment: it works absolutely fine .but the which you have made using inframe that is what i would need to save as the object tbl which contains multiple list inside. Since all the table information are in that table. But when you create that tbl2 object the headers etc are now mixed up i guess

Comment: Working with a list of a list of tibbles is not easy, especially when you try to get attributes that may not exist.   This might be a better solution https://github.com/ropensci/tidypmc/issues/5